# Background Refresh Push Notifications (with content-available flag) not refreshing data after device restarted until app manually launched

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, background-process

I am utilizing the Background App Refresh feature in iOS, which can be activated via silent (or visible) push notifications containing the `content-available:1` flag. Normally, such a push notification triggers the `application didReceiveRemoteNotification` callback, where background processing occurs.

However, I've encountered an issue where this functionality ceases to work after the phone is restarted. Regardless of whether the app has been removed from the multitasking tray, **iOS does not perform background refreshes from push notifications until the app is manually reopened post device restart**.

*Interestingly, WWDC videos, notes, and documentation only discuss the scenario where background app refresh ceases if the user manually removes the app from the multitasking tray. However, I've observed a change in behavior in some iOS versions: background push notifications seem to successfully invoke app refreshes even if the app has been manually terminated.*

I've experimented with Background Processing and Background Fetch to attempt to force the system to load the app into memory, but these approaches do not resolve the issue of ignored push notifications with the `content-available:1` flag.

Any advice on how to ensure background app refresh works without requiring the user to manually reopen the app (thereby avoiding user friction) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is mentioned in documentation that device restart will cease the location /notification updates until user resume the app.

Comment: oh, I missed that one - but I cannot find it - could you post a link? I could only find "...However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again." which kind of shows that restart should actually allow didReceiveRemoteNotification to work... (it's from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application )